# add age and gender using face-api.js

Tags: javascript

How can I add age and gender to the code use face-api.js?

I have difficulty with faceapi.nets. _______________. loadFromUri ('/ models') I should add to this and how to do in faceapi.draw .____________ what to put.

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
 ]).then(startVideo)

startVideo()

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawAge(canvas, agage_gender_model)
  }, 100)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

To load the age and gender include below code snippet.

```
faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri('/models')
```

You'll also need to append withAgeAndGender() to the detections, as shown below

```
const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions().withAgeAndGender()
```

In some browsers, the way you are querying the media is deprecated. instead of

```
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
```

Use

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
  })
  .then(
    (cameraStream) => {
      video.srcObject = cameraStream;
    }
  )
```

But to display the age and gender, you need below code snippet to draw a box and label it.

```
resizedDetections.forEach( detection => {
      const box = detection.detection.box
      const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, { label: Math.round(detection.age) + " year old " + detection.gender })
      drawBox.draw(canvas)
    })
```

These changes will make your final script to look like below:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri('/models')
 ]).then(startVideo)

startVideo()

function startVideo() {
  /*
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
  */

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
  })
  .then(
    (cameraStream) => {
      video.srcObject = cameraStream;
    }
  )

}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions().withAgeAndGender()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
    resizedDetections.forEach( detection => {
      const box = detection.detection.box
      const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, { label: Math.round(detection.age) + " year old " + detection.gender })
      drawBox.draw(canvas)
    })

  }, 100)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

`const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()`

to

`const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions().withAgeAndGender()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like below. (if you are working on ubuntu you have to use ./models for import instead of /models)

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
 //i used ./models because im working on ubuntu
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('./models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('./models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
  faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri('./models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}
    
video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions().withAgeAndGender()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
    resizedDetections.forEach( detection => {
      const box = detection.detection.box
      const drawBox = new faceapi.draw.DrawBox(box, { label: Math.round(detection.age) + " year old " + detection.gender })
      drawBox.draw(canvas)
    })
  }, 500)
})
```